# How do I declare a jquery object using the model in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass an object from my view to controller using jquery after a button click. It works if I create an object in jquery that matches my model object but I was hoping I could somehow declare the jquery object using my existing class in my model.

Here is my code for making it work with a separate jquery object that matches my model:

controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestNs
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(TestModel m)
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Test(TestModel m)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", m);
        }
    }
}
```

model

```
namespace TestNs
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

    }

}
```

view

```
@using TestNs;
@model TestModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<p id="name">Bill</p>
<p id="location">NY</p>

<button type="button" class="button" id="add-button">Add</button>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).on("click", "#add-button", function () {

        var url = "@Url.Action("Test","Home")";

        var m = { Name: "", Location: "" }; //how to declare this using TestModel????

        m.Name = $('#name').html();

        m.Location = $('#location').html();

        $.post(url, m, function(res){

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: `{ Name: "", Location: "" }` this is a JavaScript object, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Good point. So how do I declare a javascript object using my mvc model?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out to do this. Basically I'm trying to pass a model or object back and forth between the controller and the view various ways. The key part was @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)). That allows you to declare a javascript object using your model class. The point is to be able to pass data around easily without it becoming a mess. Just use one class.

Here I create an object with the TestModel class with 2 properties Name and Location. Then I pass it from the Index action method to the View using MVC razor. Then if you click the "Do Something" button I declare a javascript object using the same TestModel, reassign the values and pass it to the "DoSomething action method with an ajax post. Then the DoSomething action method passes the TestModel back to the view in the ajax jquery method.

controller

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace TestNs
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            TestModel tm = new TestModel();
            tm.Name = "Suzie";
            tm.Location = "Mongolia";
            return View(tm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DoSomething(TestModel tm)
        {
            string strJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(tm);
            return Json(strJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

view

```
@using TestNs;
@model TestModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<p id="name1">@Model.Name</p>
<p id="location1">@Model.Location</p>

<br />
<br />

<p id="name2">Bill</p>
<p id="location2">NY</p>

<button type="button" id="do-something">Do Something</button>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).on("click", "#do-something", function () {

        //declare tm object using TestModel class
        var tm = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        //reassign tm object properties for whatever reason
        tm.Name = $('#name2').html();
        tm.Location = $('#location2').html();

        //post values to action method
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/DoSomething",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(tm),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            //return tm from action method
            success: function (response) {

                var tm = $.parseJSON(response);

                alert(tm.Name + " " + tm.Location);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error!");
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

model

```
namespace TestNs
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

    }

}
```